# git: Suddenly can't push, or clone, or anything

Tags: git, github

Out of the blue, I can't push, or clone or pull with git.

I used to push successfully all the time. I don't remember doing anything unusual, but today it just stopped working. (I'm using git-gui on XP.) Whenever I try to push, the program waits for like 4 minutes and then gives me this:

```
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Pushing to git@github.com:cool-RR/physicsthing.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried reinstalling git-gui, didn't help. I tried to clone my repo from github in a separate folder, got a similar message. Pageant is loaded with my key. I tried getting a new key, didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: And? How did it go? Was it the server?

Comment: No. After re-installing like 5 times it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me the other day. It was because GitHub was down briefly. I pushed again a few minutes later and it was fine.

Comment: It's been like that for at least an hour, and I don't see GitHub's support site being flooded with similar complaints.

Comment: Just relating my personal experience when I saw the same message.

Comment: http://status.github.com is also a good place to look at to see if they are experiencing issues.